# f.open() issue resulting in Unbound error for f.close()

Tags: file-io, scope, type-conversion, try-catch, pass-by-reference

I don't quite have an answer but I'm narrowing it down. Somehow I'm mixing/confusing types, I believe, between what is provided by commands like 'os.path' and type str().

As I've made the assignment of the logfile(s) globally, even though I can print it in the function, when the variable is used in `fout = open(...` it's actually a null that's being referenced, i.e. `open()` doesn't like/can't use the type it finds.

The error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fout' referenced before assignment
```

I am simply writing a log of dot files (left on USB drives by OSX) for deletion, but the try/except is now falling over. First the original version.

working code:

```
logFile = "/Users/dee/Desktop/dotFile_names.txt"
try:
   fout = open(logFile, 'w')
   for line in dotFile_names:
       fout.write(line)
except IOError as e:
   print ("Error : %s not found." % fout)
finally:
   fout.close()
```

Attempting better practice, I sought to put the log file specs and path as variables so they can be modified if need be - I hope to make it cross platform workable. these variables are at the head of the program, i.e. not in main(), but I pass them in and print() statements have shown me they are successfully being referenced. i.e. I get this printed:

```
/Users/dee/Desktop/dotFile_names.txt
```

Despite this the error I get is:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fout' referenced before assignment - 
error points at the "fout.close()" line
```

Error producing code

```
logFilespec = "dotFile_names.txt"
fullLogFileSpec = []
userDesktop = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')
fullLogFilespec = os.path.join(userDesktop, logFilespec)
try:
    print "opening " + fullLogFilespec
    fout = open(fullLogFileSpec, 'w')
    for line in dotFile_names:
        print "..", # are we executing this line..?
        fout.write(line)
except IOError as e:
    print ("Error : %s not found." % fout)
finally:
    print "\nclosing " + fullLogFilespec
    fout.close()
```

I've found that if I modify this line by converting to a string

```
fout = open(fullLogFileSpec, 'w')
fout = open(str(fullLogFileSpec), 'w')
```

the error goes away, BUT NO file is created on the Desktop!
At the very least I guess that I am passing something unrecognisable to `fout = open()` but it is not being caught by the except. Then when I pass something that does seem to allow fout =open() to work it seems to be a ghost?

So I figure I am lost between a String and whatever kind of reference/pointer os.path.expanduser() gives me.

I'm sure it's insanely simple. Before adding the str() code I also checked all indentation, removing them all and adding back using the editor indent hotkeys, just in case that was affecting things somehow.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like I was wearing my dumb glasses, I think declaring

```
fullLogFileSpec = []
```

as a list instead of a string was my error.

Similar as it is, having re-written it without that list declaration this code is working fine:

```
logfile_directory = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Desktop')
log_bf_file_spec = 'ItemsFoundByFolder_' + Deez_1.current_datetime() + '.txt'
log_by_folder = os.path.join(logfile_directory, log_bf_file_spec)
```

the function later calls, with no error:

```
fout_by_folder = open(log_by_folder, 'w')
```